# Very Large RMSE with Linear Regression

Tags: regression, python, rms

I am working on a regression problem that has about 180 binary features and approximately 280,000 data samples.

For certain train-test splits of my data, the resulting linear-regression model (implemented in python using pandas and scikit-learn) will yield an RMSE that is orders of magnitude greater than what I typically get (for example, I expect around 6.4 RMSE, and sometimes I will get an RMSE that is 7 orders of magnitude greater than that).  Needless to say, these astronomically-large error values are destroying my average RMSE.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: *Outliers*. Check for outliers...

Comment: also, how are you splitting them? cross validation?

Comment: @usεr11852: Great suggestion. No outliers as far as I can tell. Also, no sign of values like NaN or inf.

Comment: A few observations: (1) The weights for the model are mostly very large or very small numbers, e.g. 7.16114818e+11. (2) All of my features are binary with value 1 or 0.  Could large absolute weights plus binary features with 1 or 0 value cause this problem?

Comment: Why do you expect a 6.4 RMSE ? What is the variance of the original data ?

Comment: @RUser4512: Every RMSE value that I have received for every model that I have built so far using different train-test splits has been around one of two extremes: 6.4 or 8.6e+5. I don't understand this wild fluctuation.

Comment: Let's say you have a model `m` and lets say you do $k$-fold cross-validation. If one of the folds give you huge RMSE compared to the other something is awfully odd with that fold. Plot/visualize that fold for starters. Check if the design matrix $X$ it defines is rank-degenerate, etc.

Comment: Did you check that you have a full rank design matrix in all subsamples?